# How to store and retrieve value of selected branch code from local storage client side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor-pages, c#-7.0, asp.net-core-7.0

I work or razor page asp.net core 7 . I face issue I can't store value of selected branch

value option on local storage when select option or change selection of branch from drop down list.

and retrieve value of selected branch  when click search button  .

this suppose store on Local storage of client side browser .

so please How to do that ?

```
<form id="FrmShelfLabelPrintrSetup" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-12 row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2">
                <label for="branch-selectlbl"
                    style="margin-left:3px;font-size:15px;font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;font-weight: bold;">Print
                    Server</label>
                <select id="branch-select" asp-for="SelectedBranchId" name="selectbranchid" class="form-select"
                    style="margin-left:3px;font-size:15px;font-family: 'Open Sans' , sans-serif;font-weight: bold;"
                    onchange="toggleButtonVisibility()">
                    <option value="0">--Select--</option>
                    @foreach (var branches in Model.branches)
                    {
                    <option value="@branches.iBranchCode">@branches.vBranchDesc</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2">
                <br>
                <button id="Searchtxt" type="submit" name="searchButton" value="search" asp-page-handler="Search"
                    style="width:100px;margin-top:7px;" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
                <button id="createTxt" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CreateshelflabelModal"
                    style="width:100px;margin-top:7px;margin-left:7px;display:none;"
                    class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

on page model How to retrieve value of selected branch from local storage client side

```
public class ShelfLabelPrinterSetUpModel : PageModel
{
    public async Task OnPostSearchAsync(string selectbranchid)
    {
        // how to read value of local storage here when click search button 
    }
}
```